# How to assign one variable and pass another with post in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model

I want to take some info from my model, edit one variable and pass it to post function. Here is my model:

```
public class TaskInputModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Input Value")]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public long InputId { get; set; }

    public MetriceModelTaskShedule[] Tasks;
}
```

and this is my Index.cshtml:

```
@model MetriceWeb.Models.TaskInputModel

@foreach (var item in Model.Tasks)
    {

        using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Task)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model =>  model.Value)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Value)
    </div>

    @Html.Hidden("Model.InputId", Model.InputId)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
        }
}
```

I'm receiving this like that:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TaskInputModel model)
    {
        ...
    }
```

When I'm submitting only InputId has some value, Value is always 0. When i delete line: @Html.Hidden("Model.InputId", Model.InputId) Value is ok, but i don't know how to receive InputId. Can you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Problem solved. I just had to use @Html.Hidden("InputId", Model.InputId) instead of @Html.Hidden("Model.InputId", Model.InputId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I just had to use @Html.Hidden("InputId", Model.InputId) instead of @Html.Hidden("Model.InputId", Model.InputId)